# Disable Automatic Receipts on Existing Recurring Donations

Tags: civicontribute

I'm on CiviCRM 5.8.1 on WordPress using the latest version of the Stripe extension, and I'm wondering if there's a way to disabled the automated receipts for existing recurring donations.

We'd like to change to a model where we're doing thank yous manually as needed when recurring donations come in, and while we can tell it not to send a receipt when we first enter a donation, I don't see anywhere that I can tell it to stop sending automated receipts if it's already doing it.

I do not have the "send receipt" box checked in the contribution page configuration for what that's worth.

Thanks for any ideas folks have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Recurring Contribution series itself you can set Email Receipt to Off; if you have access to mysql you can stop sending CiviCRM Contribution receipts for all your existing Recurring series by setting is_email_receipt = 0 ( in civicrm_contribution_recur )

For the iATS extension we have added an additional setting that will override (a global setting) all individual recurring series.

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- interesting thing is if I go to the recurring contribution itself there's no edit link, only view or cancel. If I go to individual contributions in the series, the send receipt box is unchecked. I'll check the DB route and see what that looks like. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's possible that we add expose extra fields in the GUI (in the iATS Extension) - this field is definitively a native civicrm field from the recurring table though. You should find it!

Comment: Thanks -- I'll dig into that more. Definitely doesn't show up on the Stripe extension but I'll poke around and post an issue for the extension if I can't find anything. Really appreciate the detailed info.

Comment: For a token-based recurring payment processor like stripe, the extension authors just need to add the getEditableRecurringScheduleFields method to their payment object and include is_email_receipt in the returned array.

Comment: could this be done in the API explorer?